# Too many records when joining two tables

Tags: ms-access-2007

I have following two tables

```
Table 1
=======

T1Col1  T1Col2  T1Col3

jkl     nnn     qoq
efg     Aaa     wow
efg     xxx     yoy
abc     iii     qoq
abc     fff     wow
abc     rrr     qoq
gdg     ppp     yoy



Table 2
=======

T2Col1  T2Col2  

qoq     nnn     
wow     aaa 
yoy     xxx
```

Link column between two table is T1.T1Col3 and T2.T2Col1

```
Expected Results
================

T1Col1  T1Col2  T1Col3  T2Col2

jkl     nnn     qoq      nnn
efg     Aaa     wow      aaa 
efg     xxx     yoy      xxx 
abc     iii     qoq      nnn
abc     fff     wow      aaa 
abc     rrr     qoq      nnn
gdg     ppp     yoy      xxx
```

With join query I am getting multiple records. But I am after the above no of records ONLY. Because
In my real scenario Table 1 got more than million records. So ultimate result set records count is 
huge which exceeds MS ACCESS limitation

Is this possible

Cheers

Shabar

Comment: One more thing here I have duplicate records in Table2.T2Col1

Comment: Edit your question to include the actual query you tried.

Answer (score 2):

Have you created relationship between tables..??
until you don't create relationship it would give a result which is called Cartesian product..!!

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the count function in the query builder.  In the section where group by is selected try the drop box and select Count.

Comment: Thax for your reply. Perhaps needs to get rid of duplicates first I believe